# How are objects instantiated by XAML?

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, xaml, mvvm

I'm developing a WPF application using the MVVM pattern and Entity Framework.  I wrote a class that contains a bunch of lists that get populated from the database.  The lists are used to populate `ComboBoxes` and other `ItemsControls.

Here's the basic structure:

```
namespace MiniManager.ViewModel
{
    public class LookupLists
    {
        public LookupLists()
        {
            using (var db = new ModelContext())
            {
                Supervisors = db.Users.ToList().Where(u => u.Supervisor);
                // More lists...
            }
        }

        public IEnumerable<User> Supervisors { get; set; }
        // More lists...
    }
}
```

I use the class in the view like this:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <lists:LookupLists x:Key="LookupLists"/>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

When I need to use it on a control I bind to a property in the resource:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource LookupLists},
                        Path=Supervisors}"/>
```

My question is this:

- How long does the `LookupLists` object last?

  - As long as the UI is active?
  - Is a new instance of `LookupLists` created (and therefore the database queried) every time the view needs it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on **where** and **how** you declare your resource:

Where:

- if you declare it as a **local resource** of a `UserControl` then it will be primarily referenced by this object and will last as long as the object lasts and the **GC** does not collect the memory
- if you declare it as a **global resource** in the `App.xaml` file then it will be available during the whole lifetime of the application

How:

- by default resources are **shared** so only one instance is created and every reference, e.g. through `StaticResource`, points to the same unique object
- if you declare the resource as `x:Shared="False"` then each reference will trigger the generation of a new instance

Answer (score 3):

Items declared in `Resources` are added to a special collection that is a member of `FrameworkElement`. Thus, the collection will live as long as the control does.

Unless the control is destroyed, no additional queries will be made (unless you make them of course).

See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.resources(v=vs.110).aspx) for more info on the `Resources` property, which is where these are stored.